# Norm of a system of and integral operator

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, operator-theory, integral-inequality, integral-equations

Let $T$ be the vector-valued integral operator defined by
$$ 
\begin{eqnarray*}
T &:&L^{2}(0,1)\times L^{2}(0,1)\longrightarrow L^{2}(0,1)\times L^{2}(0,1), \\
(u,v)^{t} &\mapsto &T(u,v)^{t}=\int_{0}^{1}K(s,x)(u,v)^{t}ds \\
&=&\int_{0}^{1}\left( 
\begin{array}{cc}
K_{11}(s,x) & K_{12}(s,x) \\ 
K_{21}(s,x) & K_{22}(s,x)%
\end{array}%
\right) \left( 
\begin{array}{c}
u(s) \\ 
v(s)%
\end{array}%
\right) ds
\end{eqnarray*}$$
where $K_{i,j}$ are smooth enough.
I want to find the norm or at least an optimal one of $T$ in the space $L^{2}(0,1)\times L^{2}(0,1)$ in function of $K_{i,j}$.
My idea is to apply $K$ on both $(u,v)$ and bound the operator $T$ but it is very restrictive.
\begin{eqnarray*}
&&\left\Vert T(u,v)^{t}\right\Vert _{L^{2}(0,1)\times L^{2}(0,1)} \\
&=&\left\Vert \left(
\int_{0}^{1}K_{11}(s,x)u(s)+K_{12}(s,x)v(s)ds,%
\int_{0}^{1}K_{21}(s,x)u(s)+K_{22}(s,x)v(s)ds\right) \right\Vert
_{L^{2}(0,1)\times L^{2}(0,1)} \\
&=&\max \left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\left\Vert \int_{0}^{1}K_{11}(s,x)u(s)+K_{12}(s,x)v(s)ds\right\Vert
_{L^{2}(0,1)} \\ 
,\left\Vert \int_{0}^{1}K_{11}(s,x)u(s)+K_{12}(s,x)v(s)ds\right\Vert
_{L^{2}(0,1)}%
\end{array}%
\right\} ,
\end{eqnarray*}

but
\begin{eqnarray*}
&&\left\Vert \int_{0}^{1}K_{11}(s,x)u(s)+K_{12}(s,x)v(s)ds\right\Vert
_{L^{2}(0,1)} \\
&\leq &\left\Vert \int_{0}^{1}K_{11}(s,x)u(s)ds\right\Vert
_{L^{2}(0,1)}+\left\Vert \int_{0}^{1}K_{12}(s,x)v(s)ds\right\Vert
_{L^{2}(0,1)} \\
&\leq &\sqrt{\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}K_{11}^{2}(s,x)dsdx}\left\Vert
u\right\Vert _{L^{2}(0,1)}+\sqrt{\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}K_{12}^{2}(s,x)dsdx}%
\left\Vert v\right\Vert _{L^{2}(0,1)}.....
\end{eqnarray*}
and so on. I want to find an optimal way to estimate the norm of $T$ in an optimal way. Any ideas guys?.
Thank you in advance.